# Removing a part of a doubly linked list

Tags: c, doubly-linked-list

I'm supposed to write a function in **C**  that remove a part of  a doubly linked list from position "a" to position "b" in the list  and paste that removed  part in another list called "trash",
 I've written this function but I didn't get the right output:

```
typedef struct list  // I defined the structure outside the main function:                          
    {   
    int data ;
    struct list *next;
    struct list *precedent;
       }node;

void cut(node *x) // x is the pointer referring to the head of the 
                                 list 
    {
    int a,b,j=1;
    node *starttrash,*sup,*endtrash;
    starttrash=(node*)malloc(sizeof(node));
    starttrash->precedent=NULL;
    starttrash->next=endtrash;
    starttrash->data=0;
    endtrash=(node*)malloc(sizeof(node));
    endtrash->precedent=starttrash;
    endtrash->next=NULL;
    endtrash->data=0;
    printf("enter the value of  a \n");
    scanf("%d",&a);
    printf("enter the value of  b \n");
    scanf("%d",&b);
    while(j<b)
    {
      if(j>a)
            {
                starttrash->next=x;
                endtrash->precedent=x;
                x->next=x->next->next;
                sup=sup->next;
           }
           else x=x->next;
    j++;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If a to b nodes has to be removed, there is no need to create new nodes for a and b.
Just glue a->precedent to b->next and nodes in between can be taken off as trash node. in if (j > a) block, no need to assign endtrash repeatedly but condition if (j == b) can be used to get b node. On same condition you can break loop.